# Django Channels : WebSocket connection failed

Tags: javascript, django, websocket, django-channels

WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/room/ws/tech' failed

I am trying to learn about creating a real time Django application using channels and following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SF1k_Twr9cg) tutorial.

However, when I am trying to create a websocket, it is throwing me this error in console : `WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/tech/' failed`

This is how I am trying to create a websocket -

```
console.log("roomname: "+roomName);
    const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://'
        + window.location.host
        + '/ws/'
        + roomName
        + '/'
    );
```

Rest assurred that url is getting built correctly. When I replace the url part with 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/room/ws/tech' and run manually in a browser console, it is throwing me the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Channels 4.0.0 does not start the ASGI server by default. So, **Try adding 'daphne' to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py**.

First pip

```
pip install -U 'channels[dapne]' channels-redis
```

Then in your Django settings file:

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "daphne",
    ...
]
```

See the Channels 4.0.0 release notes for more info: *https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releases/4.0.0.html?highlight=INSTALLED_APPS#release-notes*

---

**Alternative Solution**

Lowering the version of the channel to **3.0.5** seemed to work.

Try

```
pip uninstall channels
pip install channels==3.0.5
```